# Most idiomatic way to double every character in a string in Rust

Tags: string, rust

I have a `String`, and I want to make a new `String`, with every character in the first one doubled. So `"abc"` would become `"aabbcc"` and so on.

The best I've come up with is:

```rust
let mut result = String::new();
for c in original_string.chars() {
    result.push(c);
    result.push(c);
}
result
```

This works fine. but is there a more succinct (or more idiomatic) way to do this?

In JavaScript I would probably write something like:

```
original.split('').map(c => c+c).join('')
```

Or in Ruby:

```rb
(original.chars.map { |c| c+c }).join('')
```

Since Rust also has functional elements, I was wondering if there is a similarly succinct solution.

Comment: Amusingly, neither JS nor Ruby have lazy iterators by default, so your example cases make 2 intermediate arrays that just take up unneeded space and time. Your Rust example (and the answers below) do not.

Comment: @Shepmaster I know that. Performance wasn't really what I was asking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use `std::iter::repeat` to repeat every `char` value from the input. This creates an infinite iterator, but for your case we only need to iterate **2 times**, so we can use [`take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take) to limit our iterator, then flatten all the iterators that hold the doubled `char`s.

```rust
use std::iter;

fn main() {
    let input = "abc"; //"abc".to_string();

    let output = input
        .chars()
        .flat_map(|c| iter::repeat(c).take(2))
        .collect::<String>();

    println!("{:?}", output);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4ed93362a552e6fe54a522a01d590fa7)

**Note:** To double we are using `take(2)` but you can use any `usize` to increase the repetition.

Comment: You can use the [iterator solution *and* reserve space](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=34c041fbd1a4755ca2126527c6ab1af0) in the string, if profiling shows a benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would just do exactly what you're doing. Its intent is clear (more clear than the functional approaches you presented from JavaScript or Ruby, in my opinion) and it is efficient. The only thing I would change is perhaps reserve space for the characters, since you know exactly how much space you will need.

```
let mut result = String::with_capacity(original_string.len() * 2);
```

However, if you are really in love with this style, you could use `flat_map`

```
let result: String = original_string.chars()
    .flat_map(|c| std::iter::repeat(c).take(2))
    .collect();
```

Comment: I would disagree with the loop being easier to understand. The iterator approach doesn’t require me to run the loop in my head to validate it does what I want.

Comment: @Listerone: Run the loop in your head? I have no idea what that means.